# Does StringFormat feature of WPF Xaml work on Label.Content?

Tags: wpf, xaml, label, string-formatting

I have bind my Amount **Label's** Content Property to a decimal property via DataContext. I am trying to apply stringformat but see no effect. Does **StringFormat** feature work on Label controls ?? Please tell me on which controls does this feature work. BTW following is the code for the Label Control for whom i want to apply the currency formatting

```
<Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,10,0,0" Name="tb" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="120" />
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`StringFormat` works on properties of type string (when the object you are binding to is being converted to a string the string format is applied). The `Content` property is of type `Object`.

You can place a TextBlock inside your label to achieve the desired effect:

```
<Label Grid.Column="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,10,0,0" Name="tb" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="120">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat={}{0:C}}"/>
</Label>
```

Comment: This is really a strange situation. I am able to apply string format for GridViewColumns and Textblock defined in a dataTemplate in App.xaml but when i define the same TextBlock in Page, it's not working ?? 

Does StringFormatting works when control is binded to DataContext ??

Comment: OK, as I understand it, two conditions must be met in order the StringFormat to work: the target property of your binding should be of type string (like "Text" property on the text block) and the source property ("Amount") should NOT be a string. Also read the documentation on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx.

Answer (score 28):

Try `ContentStringFormat`

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/866f7934-8b10-4872-b306-122674fad5fa/

```
<Label Content=”{Binding Amount}” ContentStringFormat=”C” />
```

Comment: ContentStringFormat only works as of .NET 4.0, though. But this is certainly much cleaner than the accepted answer.

Comment: For posterity: if you start a ContentStringFormat with a `{0}`, don't forget to put `{}` before it. So make it `ContentStringFormat="{}{0} some text here"`

Comment: This works well until you don't want the string format to apply on a TargetNullValue, then the format needs to be in the same binding as TargetNullValue and binding path, which means Pavlo's answer is needed