# What's the XAML equivalent of .toFixed(2)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, string-formatting

I want to display a number in a `Label`, it should be formatted with 2 decimal places (always).

**Example:**

```
<Label Content="{Binding MyMoneyAmount}" />
```

If `MyMoneyAmount` = 100, then it should display as: *100.00* not *100*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this SO [Does StringFormat work on Label Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782914/does-stringformat-feature-of-wpf-xaml-work-on-label-content) and also my own testing, StringFormat won't work on a Label as Content is of type Object as reflected in another answer on this page.

You can use this workaround (to display for example as a currency):

```
<Label><TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={myValue}, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}" /></Label>
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. I have been trying various examples on the net, I didn't realize that the problem was the `Label`

Comment: Glad to help - note that using C2 instead of N2 will also bring in your culture's currency symbol

Comment: +1 @GrahamMc - you are absolutely right, I was concentrating more on the usage of StringFormat in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
<Label Content="{Binding MyMoneyAmount, StringFormat={0:F2}}" />
```

Comment: According to my reading and a quick test in Blend 4, StringFormat won't work here because Content is of type Object - see my answer